# How to make an AAM of Intranet zone of web app use the external url of Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, office-integration, owa

The office web app farm is configured with internal url and external url, the sharepoint farm is configured with external-https WOPIZone .   The web application has a default zone and an AAM of Intranet zone. the default zone is using the internal url of the OWA farm and the intranet zone is also using the internal zone, how do I make the intranet zone to use the external url of the OWA farm.